# MPI_Bcast: Efficiency advantages?

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, message-passing

In MPI, is `MPI_Bcast` purely a convenience function or is there an efficiency advantage to using it instead of just looping over all ranks and sending the same message to all of them?

Rationale:  `MPI_Bcast`'s behavior of sending the message to everyone, including the root, is inconvenient for me, so I'd rather not use it unless there's a good reason, or it can be made to not send the message to root.

Comment: Why is having the root of the MPI_Bcast participate an issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using MPI_Bcast will definitely  be more efficient than rolling your own. A lot of work has been done in all MPI implementations to optimise collective operations based on factors such as the message size and the communication architecture.

For example, [MPI_Bcast in MPICH2 would use a different algorithm depending on the size of the message](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~thakur/papers/mpi-coll.pdf). For short messages, a binary tree is used to minimise processing load and latency. For long messages, it is implemented as a binary tree scatter followed by an allgather.

In addition, HPC vendors often provide MPI implementations that make efficient use of the underlying interconnects, especially for collective operations. For example, it is possible to use a [hardware supported multicast scheme](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~panda/788/slides/5a_5d_collective.pdf) or to [use bespoke algorithms that can take advantage of the existing interconnects](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.133.5828&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 4):

The collective communications can be *much* faster than rolling your own.   All of the MPI implmementations spend a lot of time working on those routines to be fast.

If you routinely want to do collective-type things but only on a subset of tasks, then you probably want to create your own sub-communicators and use BCAST, etc on those communicators.

Comment: Even with an alternate comm, the root of that comm will still participate in the collective operation.  The OP specifically mentioned that having the root get the message was an issue.

Comment: The root "sending" the message to itself is a null operation, not even a memory copy.

Answer (score 3):

`MPI_Bcast` sends the message from one process (the 'root') to all *others*, by definition. It probably will be a little faster than just looping over all processes, too. The `mpich2` implementation, for instance, uses a binomial tree to distribute the message.

In case you don't want to broadcast to MPI_COMM_WORLD, but you want to define subgroups, you can go about it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define NPROCS 8

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank, new_rank, sendbuf, recvbuf,
    ranks1[4]={0,1,2,3}, ranks2[4]={4,5,6,7};

    MPI_Group orig_group, new_group;
    MPI_Comm new_comm;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    sendbuf = rank;

    /* Extract the original group handle */
    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &orig_group);

    /* Divide tasks into two groups based on rank */
    if (rank < NPROCS/2) {
        MPI_Group_incl(orig_group, NPROCS/2, ranks1, &new_group);
    } else {
        MPI_Group_incl(orig_group, NPROCS/2, ranks2, &new_group);
    }

    /* Create new communicator and then perform some comm
     * Here, MPI_Allreduce, but you can MPI_Bcast at will
     */
    MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_group, &new_comm);
    MPI_Allreduce(&sendbuf, &recvbuf, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, new_comm);
    MPI_Group_rank (new_group, &new_rank);

    printf("rank= %d newrank= %d recvbuf= %d\n", rank, new_rank, recvbuf); 

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Which might produce something like the following output:

```
rank= 7 newrank= 3 recvbuf= 22
rank= 0 newrank= 0 recvbuf= 6 
rank= 1 newrank= 1 recvbuf= 6 
rank= 2 newrank= 2 recvbuf= 6 
rank= 6 newrank= 2 recvbuf= 22
rank= 3 newrank= 3 recvbuf= 6
rank= 4 newrank= 0 recvbuf= 22
rank= 5 newrank= 1 recvbuf= 22
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that the MPI_Bcast is probably faster than a loop, in the general case.  In general, the MPI collectives are optimized over a wide range of message sizes, comm sizes, and specific rank layouts.

That said, it may be possible to beat a collective at specific message sizes, comm sizes, and rank layouts.  For instance, a loop over non-blocking point to point calls (e.g. ISend and Recv/IRecv) may be faster...but probably only at a few specific message sizes, comm sizes, and rank layouts.

If the specific algorithm that you are coding needs the pattern of a Bcast (e.g. all ranks get the same data payload from a root), then use the Bcast collective.  In general, it is not worth adding complication by rolling your own "collective replacements".

If there is some other message pattern that the algorithm needs, and a Bcast on only a partial fit...then it may be worth rolling your own...but personally I set that bar rather high.

Comment: I agree.  
It's way easier simply to tune the parameters of the collectives (manually through command line arguments/environment variables, or automatically through something like mpitune for IntelMPI) then to rewrite your own performant collectives.